# Django keyword error but print kwargs shows the key

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have this URL and I send the currently logged in user's id (viewer (33)) and the id of the user being looked at (user (1)) in the URL:

```
path("users/<int:viewer>/<int:user>/profile/", OtherProfile.as_view()),
```

Here is the view handling that URL:

```
class OtherProfile(generics.RetrieveAPIView):
    permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticated]
    serializer_class = ProfileSerializer
    name = "other-profile"
    lookup_field = "user"
    def get_queryset(self):
        breakpoint()
        viewer = self.kwargs["viewer"]
        user = self.kwargs["user"]
        return Profile.objects.all().filter(user_id=user)
```

There is a breakpoint here and the result of

print(self.kwargs["viewer"]) gives 33 which is correct

print(self.kwargs["user"]) gives 1 which is also correct

Here is the profile serializer as specified in the serializer_class:

```
class ProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    location = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    user = UserSerializer()
    followers = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = [
            "id",
            "background",
            "photo",
            "first_name",
            "middle_name",
            "last_name",
            "birthdate",
            "gender",
            "bio",
            "occupation",
            "is_verified",
            "verification",
            "website",
            "location",
            "user",
            "followers",
            "created_at",
            "updated_at",
        ]
    def get_location(self, obj):
        location_obj = Location.objects.filter(profile=obj.id)
        if location_obj:
            location_obj = Location.objects.get(profile=obj.id)
            location = LocationSerializer(location_obj)
            return location.data

    def get_followers(self, obj):
        breakpoint()
        followers = Follow.objects.filter(followee=obj.user.id)
        return followers.count()
```

I put a breakpoint on the get_followers method so I can look at the data.

print(self.context["view"].kwargs) - prints ["viewer", "user"]

My question:

Why does print(self.context["view"].kwargs["user"]) print 33 when on the view the kwargs user should be 1?

Why does it give me a key error when I try and print(self.context["view"].kwargs["viewer"])?

Comment: what does `self.context["view"].kwargs` print in the second case? it's very hard to solve this without being able to reproduce the code. I think you need to try more breakpoints/understand the flow of your code better to understand where things could be going wrong

Comment: if you can create a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) I'm sure someone will solve this asap. It has also often happened to me when I try to create these minimal examples of what is going wrong, I just see what is wrong myself. Simplifying the problem down to it's core elements can really help